# Backbone view 1 pass value to another view 2

Tags: backbone.js

This is the first view content ,where the second view is loaded to first view as a child.

```
  define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone',
            'text!../../../../school-admin/classManagement.html',
            'views/schoolModule/stdManagementView'],
    function($, _, Backbone, hrManagementTemplate,StdManagementView) {
        var ClassManagementView = Backbone.View
                .extend({
                    // target item.
                    el : $("#schoolContentOuterPnl"),
                    render : function() {
                        var data = {};
                        // template
                        var compiledTemplate = _.template(hrManagementTemplate, data);
                        // append the item to the view's target
                        this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
                    },
                    // Event Handlers
                    events : {
                        "click #btnStdInClassManagement" : "loadStdInClassManagement",
                        },

                    loadStdInClassManagement : function(){
                       //Here i want to pass value to another view
                        new StdManagementView({
                            el : $("#classManagementContenTtabContent")
                        });
                    },
                });
        return new ClassManagementView;
    });
```

This is my second view ,when the event on the first view is triggered.

```
  define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'datatables',
                    'text!../../../../school-admin/stdManagement.html' ],
            function($, _, Backbone, datatables,  stdManagementTemplate) {
                var StdManagementView = Backbone.View.extend({
                            initialize: function(){
                                this.render();
                            },
                            render : function() {
                                var data = {};
                                // template
                                var compiledTemplate = _.template(
                                        stdManagementTemplate, data);
                                // append the item to the view's target
                                this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
                                },
                            // Event Handlers
                            events : {},
                                });
            return StdManagementView;
            });
```

From the above code how can i pass a dynamic value from view 1 to view 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it looks like you only want to pass in a value once when you create your second view. As such you can just pass it in to the [constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) of your second view and it will be part of the options object passed in.

For example

```
//view 1
loadStdInClassManagement : function(){
   //Here i want to pass value to another view
        new StdManagementView({
          el : $("#classManagementContenTtabContent"),
          someValue: 'something'
    });
 }


//view 2
 var StdManagementView = Backbone.View.extend({
         initialize: function(options){
         this.someValue = options.someValue; 
         this.render();
   },
```

Comment: yah its worked.thnx
But how can i go to the parent page ,when i'm on child page.The URL is same.Please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by going to the parent page, do you mean hiding the child view and re-displaying the parent view? Are they being rendered in the same element?

Comment: yes exactly..child is  rendered  in parent element.

Comment: It's hard to say without having a better idea of how your app is structured. However one approach you can take is to maintain a reference to your child view in your parent view, and then listen to some event on that child view which you can trigger in your child view. If your setup is more complicated you might want to ask a second question with the specific details related to what your trying to solve here.